# AS3: add linked BitmapData to stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to add a sprite to a stage made from bitmapData I link to from the library with the identifier `pointerGraphic`, here's my code:

**Pointer.as**

```
package com.George.BMIapp
{
    import pointerGraphic;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;

    public class Pointer extends Sprite
    {

        const graphic:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new pointerGraphic(0,0));

        private var _pointer:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public function get sprite():Sprite
        {
            return this;
        }

        public function Pointer(y:int, minX:int, maxX:int)
        {
            _pointer.addChild(graphic);
            addChild(_pointer);
            _pointer.x = minX;
            _pointer.y = y;
        }

    }

}
```

and I initialise it like so:

```
import com.George.BMIapp.Pointer;

//Constants for pointer movement
var POINTER_MIN_X:int = 68;
var POINTER_MAX_X:int = 283;

var heightPointer:Pointer = new Pointer(371, POINTER_MIN_X, POINTER_MAX_X);
```

Yet nothing appears on the stage, yet there are no errors (I'm in strict mode with debugging enabled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if your code is complete or not in the example, but for your pointer to show you need to add it to the stage. So it should be:

```
var heightPointer:Pointer = new Pointer(371, POINTER_MIN_X, POINTER_MAX_X);
addChild(heightPointer);
```

Comment: Just figured this was the problem in the comments below Hawks answer, my class attempts to add it to the stage but fails. The workaround I have found is to add a `container:Object` paramater and use `container.addChild(_pointer)` in the class and instantiate via `var heightPointer:Pointer = new Pointer(this, 371, POINTER_MIN_X, POINTER_MAX_X);`

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in a width and height of zero to your bitmapdata when creating it.

**This is incorrect. See comments.**

Comment: doesn't matter what value I put there nothing shows, those values are not used and the values of the actual image are used in the constructor. (they are dummy values but necessary)

Comment: Hawks is right, you need to provide the width and height of your BitmapData. The rest of your code seems right. I wouldn't use constants for objects created on the stack though.

Comment: Apologies that was a bad assumption about library assets behaving like normal bitmapdata then.

Comment: @Laurent see (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337237/loading-an-embedded-image-in-as3#answer-1339558) and other answers on this page for more info on this. The library asset creates an subClass of the bitmapData and the height and width variables do nothing. Changing these values does nothing, no bitmap appears.

Comment: Well I still think that's the likely candidate as the source of the error in the code as testing this myself with my own embedded bitmapdata, it works fine. I'm not saying you need width/height, I'm saying that something is going wrong with the asset perhaps.

Comment: @Hawks thanks did you use the exact same code and have tried without width and height paramaters?

Comment: Actually is it definitely creating an asset of BitmapData? Perhaps it is creating a Bitmap from your asset (like with an [Embed]) and silently failing for some reason when you pass as a constructor argument?

Comment: @George unfortunately I can't test exactly as you're using Creative Suite I guess and I'm using FlashDevelop. I used the [Embed] tag and brought my bitmap in that way. Rest of the code worked fine with it's .bitmapData I can test later in the Flash IDE but not for hours.

Comment: @Hawks pretty sure its bitmap data, using a bitmap type I get a `1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type pointerGraphic to an unrelated type flash.display:Bitmap`. I'm starting to think it could be something to do with being on a network drive.

Comment: @Hawks... ok figured out it is not the bitmapdata getting skewed... if i remove `addChild(_pointer)` from the Class, and after instantiating the class in the fla write `addChild(heightPointer)` it appears... so it is something to do with being added to the display.